# Web-browsing error: No Suitable Nodes Are Available to Perform Your Request?

Tags: internet, browser

I have tried to open some sites on my PC and instead of opening the site requested, i get this

"No Suitable Nodes are available to perform your request"

e.g  http://www.aol.com

I have contacted my service providers (MTN Nigeria) and they said the problem is not from their end.

What do I do?

Comment: I'm sorry, No Suitable Nodes Are Available To Perform Your Request :)

Comment: sorry, this is not a programming question. I've never seen that error from any web browser.

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: ALL SUITABLE NODES ARE BELONG TO US (sorry, couldn't resist...) Edit: made more sense with the original title

Answer (score 2):

The error " No suitable nodes are available to serve your request" is caused by the load balancer used by one of the websites you are visiting

Answer (score 1):

MTN Nigeria haven't got a clue. In my experience, refreshing the page usually takes care of the problem in nearly all the sites I've visited. However, thisday newspaper website is the exception. My laptop uses Windows 7.